# Вывести файлы, отсортировав по числовой составляющей имени

Tags: linux, файлы, bash, сортировка

Есть в папке некоторое колличество файлов:

```
 pre_1_filea
 pre_2_fileb
 ...
 pre_9_filek
 pre_10_filel
 ...
```

Их надо вывести отсортировав по числовой составляющей  имени файла. Префикс имени файлов `pre` всегда один и тот же для всего набора файлов и может содержать любые допустимые символы. Разделитель `_` может поменяться на `-` или еще какой другой.

Если пробую так:

```
 $ ls -1 pre*
 pre_1_filea
 pre_10_filel
 pre_2_fileb
 pre_9_filek
```

, то файлы отсортированы в алфавитном порядке.

Как отсортировать их по числовой составляющей в имени?

Пробовал так же с `sort -n -t_ -k2`, работает, но разделитель не гарантируется и может также встретиться в префиксе имени `pre`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Должна подойти сортировка по версии:

```
$ for i in {1,2,9,10}; do touch A2-V411-THZ_${i}_file; done

$ ls -1v A2-V411-THZ*
A2-V411-THZ_1_file
A2-V411-THZ_2_file
A2-V411-THZ_9_file
A2-V411-THZ_10_file
```

Из мнауала `man ls`:

> -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text

Здесь подробнее [about-version-sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html). Можно предварительно проверить, удовлетворяет ли эта сортировка структуре имени файлов:

> Version-sorted strings are compared such that if ver1 and ver2 are version numbers 
>   and prefix and suffix (suffix matching the regular expression `‘(\.[A-Za-z~][A-Za-z0-9~]*)*’`) are strings then ver1 < ver2 implies that the name composed of “prefix ver1 suffix” sorts before “prefix ver2 suffix”.

Comment: Отличный вариант! Интересно насколько это стандартный ключ...

Comment: @MaxU По моему gnu, в posix вроде нет такого

Comment: Я проверил на sles 12, работает. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Очень непрямой подход, но работает. Можно вытащить первое число из имени файла, поставить его перед именем, разделив пробелом, сортировать по числам, и убрать число:

```bash
sed -n -e 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1 \0/; p' |
    sort -n |
    awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Для следующего набора тестовых кейсов работает:

```
pre_1_file
pre_9_file
2_file
pre8_file
pre_foo_bar_3_file
pre_10_file
```

---

Если в префиксе у вас есть числа, решение немного меняется:

```bash
prefix="A2-V411-THZ"
sed -n -e "s/${prefix}[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1 \0/; p" |
    sort -n |
    awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Прошу обратить внимание на *двойные* кавычки в данном случае. Работает верно на таком наборе:

```
A2-V411-THZ_1_file
A2-V411-THZ_9_file
A2-V411-THZ-2_file
A2-V411-THZ8_file
A2-V411-THZ_foo_bar_3_file
A2-V411-THZ_10_file
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Возможно будет работать, но в prefix могут быть и числа. Префикс это  исходящий номер клиента и он один и тот же для всего набора файлов, например, что-то такое - A2-V411-THZ.

Comment: @simpleCode, `prefix="A2-V411-THZ"; sed -ne 's/${prefix}*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1 \0/; p'`, не проверял

Comment: @simpleCode См. правку.

Comment: Я проверил, вот так работает - `ls -1 A2-V411-THZ* | sed -n -e "s/${prefix}[^0-9]*([0-9]\+).*/\1 \0/; p" | sort -n | awk '{ print $2 }`. Решение интересное, я уже плюснул, больше не могу. Спасибо.